# FS100A works when Arduino connected to PC but not when connected to Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino-nano, raspberrypi, virtualwire

I am building a simple circuit which monitors soil humidity in a flower pot. I was able to measure it and send it from one Arduino Nano to another Nano via FS100A transmitter and receiver and VirtualWire library.

As this is prototype so far I connected 1st (measuring) Nano to a powerbank and it works fine: I see the data is send and received by 2nd Arduino.

2nd Nano receives the data (it is less than 50 bytes) and send send it to PC via USB serial connection. All works fine as long as 2nd Arduino is connected to anything but Raspberry PI. Then it is not able to receive any data.

I modified source code of my program to blink built-in LED right after data is read. When 2nd Nano is powered by another powerbank it blinks (the data is read). The same happens using any other PC. But when I try to use it with RPi there is no blinking.
RPi is model B+ and I tried two different devices.

I suspect that Raspberries don’t provide stable power to usb or they cause a lot of noise preventing radio from reading the data. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Try to power your Arduino with external power supply and use only RPi to receive/display your data. You will prove this way that the problem lays in the insufficient voltage. If you have a DMM you can check this by measuring voltage on RPi USB port.

Answer (score 0):

After some attempts I finally made it work.
I tried to use a level shifter. It worked somehow but I could not find any library which would work with Arduino's VirtualWire.

I just put a 220µ capacitor on power lines to the radio receiver. It filtered all the noise and Arduino is able to interpret signals correctly.

[image: wiring]